# "No suitable method found to Override" function Error in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, telerik-appbuilder

```
   public override void OnBindSwipeContentHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position)
```

Hi Friends I am working on Android app With Telerik UI for android Controls Please Help me "OnBindSwipeContentHolder" not found error How can i resolve this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Com.Telerik.Widget.List;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using System.Collections;

namespace test
{
 public class TelerikListView : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ListView);
        // Create your application here
        RadListView listview = FindViewById<RadListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(GetListOfCities());
        listview.SetAdapter(adapter);


        //CityAdapter adapterlist = new CityAdapter(GetListOfCities());
        //listview.SetAdapter(adapterlist);

        SelectionBehavior selectionBehavior = new SelectionBehavior();
        listview.AddBehavior(selectionBehavior);
        selectionBehavior.SetSelectionMode(SelectionBehavior.SelectionMode.Single);

        SelectionListener selectionListener = new SelectionListener(this, selectionBehavior);
        selectionBehavior.AddListener(selectionListener);

        SwipeExecuteBehavior swipeExecuteBehavior = new SwipeExecuteBehavior();
        listview.AddBehavior(swipeExecuteBehavior);

        SwipeExecuteListener swipeExecuteListener = new SwipeExecuteListener(adapter);
        swipeExecuteBehavior.AddListener(swipeExecuteListener);

        swipeExecuteBehavior.SwipeLimitStart = -50;
        swipeExecuteBehavior.SwipeLimitEnd = 50;


    }

    private List<City> GetListOfCities()
    {
        List<City> cities = new List<City>();
        cities.Add(new City("London", "United Kingdom"));
        cities.Add(new City("Berlin", "Germany"));
        cities.Add(new City("Madrid", "Spain"));
        cities.Add(new City("Rome", "Italy"));
        cities.Add(new City("Paris", "France"));
        cities.Add(new City("Hamburg", "Germany"));
        cities.Add(new City("Barcelona", "Spain"));
        cities.Add(new City("Munich", "Germany"));
        cities.Add(new City("Milan", "Italy"));
        cities.Add(new City("Cologne", "Germany"));
        return cities;
    }



    public override void OnBindSwipeContentHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)holder.ItemView;
        LinearLayout leftLayout = (LinearLayout)mainLayout.GetChildAt(0);
        LinearLayout rightLayout = (LinearLayout)mainLayout.GetChildAt(1);

        Button leftButton = new Button(mainLayout.Context);
        leftButton.Text = "edit";

        Button rightButton = new Button(mainLayout.Context);
        rightButton.Text = "delete";

        leftLayout.RemoveAllViews();
        leftLayout.AddView(leftButton);

        rightLayout.RemoveAllViews();
        rightLayout.AddView(rightButton);
    }

}

public class CityAdapter : ListViewAdapter
{
    public CityAdapter(IList items)
        : base(items)
    {
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.city_list_item, parent, false);
        return new CityViewHolder(view);
    }

    public override void OnBindListViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        CityViewHolder viewHolder = (CityViewHolder)holder;
        City city = (City)Items[position];
        viewHolder.nameView.Text = city.Name;
        viewHolder.countryView.Text = city.Country;
    }

    public class CityViewHolder : ListViewHolder
    {
        public TextView nameView;
        public TextView countryView;

        public CityViewHolder(View itemView)
            : base(itemView)
        {

            nameView = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.nameView);
            countryView = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.countryView);
        }
    }
}

public class SelectionCallback : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
{
    private SelectionBehavior selectionBehavior;
    public SelectionCallback(SelectionBehavior behavior)
    {
        selectionBehavior = behavior;
    }

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.MenuInflater;
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        selectionBehavior.EndSelection();
    }
}
public class SelectionListener : Java.Lang.Object,
SelectionBehavior.ISelectionChangedListener
{

    private ActionMode actionMode;
    private ActionMode.ICallback callback;
    private Activity activity;
    private SelectionBehavior selectionBehavior;

    public SelectionListener(Activity activity, SelectionBehavior selectionBehavior)
    {
        this.callback = new SelectionCallback(selectionBehavior);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.selectionBehavior = selectionBehavior;
    }

    public void OnSelectionStarted()
    {
        actionMode = activity.StartActionMode(callback);
    }
    public void OnItemIsSelectedChanged(int position, bool newValue)
    {
        int selectionCount = selectionBehavior.SelectedItems().Count;
        actionMode.Title = selectionCount.ToString();
    }
    public void OnSelectionEnded()
    {
        actionMode.Finish();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Swiping behaviour
/// </summary>
public class SwipeExecuteListener : Java.Lang.Object, SwipeExecuteBehavior.ISwipeExecuteListener
{

    private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    public SwipeExecuteListener(ListViewAdapter adapter)
    {
        listViewAdapter = adapter;
    }
    public void OnSwipeStarted(int position)
    {
    }
    public void OnSwipeProgressChanged(int position, int offset, View swipeContent)
    {
    }
    public void OnSwipeEnded(int position, int offset)
    {
        int absOffset = Math.Abs(offset);
        if (absOffset > 300)
        {
            listViewAdapter.Remove(position);
        }
        listViewAdapter.NotifySwipeExecuteFinished();
    }
    public void OnExecuteFinished(int position)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the source code of whole Class ?

Comment: I am Using this reference :- http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/controls/listview/behaviors/listview-behaviors-swipeexecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Activity` class does not have a`OnBindSwipeContentHolder` method to override.

Within Telerik, `ListViewAdapter` and `ListViewDataSourceAdapter` do:

> onBindSwipeContentHolder
>
> public void onBindSwipeContentHolder(ListViewHolder holder,
>                               int position)
>
> Called by RadListView to display the swipe content behind an item at the specified position. This method should update the contents of the com.telerik.widget.list.ListViewHolder#itemView to reflect the swipe content behind the item at the given position.

---

> In order to achieve this we will need to **override the ListViewAdapter's onBindSwipeContentHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position).**
>
> ---

I believe you have that method in the wrong class, you should be in your custom list adapter.

```
public class CityAdapter : ListViewAdapter
{

~~~~
    public override void OnBindSwipeContentHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)holder.ItemView;
        LinearLayout leftLayout = (LinearLayout)mainLayout.GetChildAt(0);
        LinearLayout rightLayout = (LinearLayout)mainLayout.GetChildAt(1);

        Button leftButton = new Button(mainLayout.Context);
        leftButton.Text = "edit";

        Button rightButton = new Button(mainLayout.Context);
        rightButton.Text = "delete";

        leftLayout.RemoveAllViews();
        leftLayout.AddView(leftButton);

        rightLayout.RemoveAllViews();
        rightLayout.AddView(rightButton);
    }

~~~~

}
```

Comment: one more problem in item select event. when am i selecting any item i am getting an exception like this Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: No super method getChildAdapterPosition(Landroid/view/View;)I in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView' appears in /data/app/test.test-1/base.apk)

Comment: Can you post new question with that error and the code so it will be easier for everyone to review and answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to override`OnBindSwipeContentHolder` method in class `TelerikListView` which inherits `Activity` class from Android. `OnBindSwipeContentHolder` class can be overriden by a class inhheriting `ListViewAdapter` (Telerik control) only.

So essentially moving the definition of `OnBindSwipeContentHolder` from `TelerikListView` class to `CityAdapter` class will solve the build error.